# Example of distribution which is not come from locally integrable function

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, distribution-theory

I was studying distribution.

Any locally integrable function can be made as distribution. I know till now all examples of distribution from locally integrable function.

Is there any example of a distribution which does not come from locally integrable function

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$u(\phi)=\phi(0)$$then $u$ is a distribution, $u\notin L^1_{loc}$.

Comment: And also $u(\phi)=\phi'(0)$ or higher derivatives (multipoles).

Comment: Thanks A lot I got now